# Generating binary objects of size N, with N being specified by the user

Tags: python

I would like to generate a binary object that is of size N, a parameter sent into a function by a user. The contents of the binary object can be anything, the size of the object is the only thing that matters. For example says 10kb is sent in as N. I would want to create a text file or some kind of object that can be stored locally on the computer that is 10kb in size. Any ideas on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: have you tried: `with open(fname, 'w+') as f: f.write("x"*n)` ?

Comment: How do you plan to verify that the user does not bypass the object size limit?

Comment: How about `ba = bytearray(N)` which will create an array of the proper size and initialize it with null bytes. You can write it to a file as @moooeeeep suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a file of size 10k:

```
with open("filename", "wb") as f:
    f.seek(10239)    # seek to 10k - 1
    f.write("\0")    # write a single byte
```

Now you have a file of 10k zero bytes.